# What are the non-library equivalents of jQuery's $('.foo', context)?

Tags: javascript, dom

That is to say how can javascript find elements (eg. those with class 'foo') within a passed subset of the document ('context', in the jQuery example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `context` is a DOM element, I believe that it inherits all of the document's DOM methods. For example:

`jQuery('.foo', context)`

..could be rewritten as:

`context.getElementsByClassName('foo')`

..so long as `context` is a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`someElem.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName).
Note that it's not supported by IE.

Comment: And this is probably one of the biggest reasons to use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM method [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName)

```
var elements = context.getElementsByClassName( 'foo' );
```

Just be aware of [its browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
context.getElementsByClass('foo');
context.querySelectorAll('.foo');
```

For some reason, IE8 supports querySelectorAll, but only IE9 supports getElementsByClassName.